# Difference between embeded GMAP and GEO location

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Please let me know the difference between keeping the google map as below
http://www.addmap.org/ which is very easy and using GEO Location API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:600px; height:500px; overflow:hidden;"><iframe width="600" 
height="500" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
q=Berry%20Street%2012%20%2C%20%20New%20York&t=m&z=14&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" 
frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe><iframe 
src="http://www.embed-google-map.com/embed-map.php?get=map-datas" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"><a href="http://www.staubers.de" 
class="map-data">staubers.de</a><style>.maps-style_map:initreaction=10false_attempt10-
border</style></iframe></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suppose the biggest difference is that with the actual direct API usage you would be able to utilize any functionality provided by the app, and thus make the Maps service usage more dynamic.

And with the addmap, you can only have what they are supporting (never used that, looks that you can just show a place on a  map), thus if that is enough for you, then I suppose go with the easy solution.

And if you doubt that you would have future needs that are not covered by the addmap, then I would suggest you learn the real API usage