# Giving Multiple Markers With embedded Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I can display a google map with a marker with below code for a given latitude and logitude. I need to display multiple makers. How do you add multiple markers?

```
 <div style="width:600px; height:500px; overflow:hidden;"><iframe width="600" height="500"  
 src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
 q=48.89364,2.33739&t=m&z=14&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed";" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
 marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe><iframe src="http://www.embed-google-
 map.com/embed-map.php?get=map-datas" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
 marginwidth="0"><a href="http://www.staubers.de" class="map-data">staubers.de</a>
  <style>.maps-style_map:initreaction=10false_attempt10-border</style></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically as I said in [Difference between embeded GMAP and GEO location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024028/difference-between-embeded-gmap-and-geo-location), if you need more functionality than its provided by the service, then you should actually use the API directly, and not via some other services.

Or do check whether the service provider would provide the functionality you are looking for.